# How to get updated properly an Ionic 4 app to upload it on Google Play store?

Tags: google-play, ionic4

i recently upload an app on GooglePS but i've got few warnings about the SDK im targeting, It seems i'm targeting 27 Sdk and it should be 29 (Don't understand about this to be honest) what is the properly way to maintenance it to the last target and to reach all the android versions possible? Any guide for to keep it up to date? Thank you very much

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To up your app  to api 29  you can add this to your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29"/>
```

Add this after `<platform name="android">`

And just build your app.